# Do positions exist in philosophical research?

Tags: philosophy

For example, in the same fashion that medical professionals might do research on cancer, does there exist comparable positions in philosophy where one "researches," say, Free Will Determinism?

Comment: Well there certainly exist philosophy professors in most universities. I don't know what sort of research they do, but that seems like the place to look.

Comment: Are you asking about "positions" for students, such as RA, or professional positions?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, for example Oxford's [philosophy faculty](https://www.philosophy.ox.ac.uk/faculty-members) includes professors of

- ancient greek philosophy
- philosophy of mind
- political philosophy
- philosophy of language
- practical ethics
- philosophy of physics
- philosophy of mathematics
- medieval philosophy
- metaphysics
- logic

Answer (score 0):

There are philosophy faculty who specialize in research on a particular topic (see @henning's answer). However, what I think is rare in philosophy and other Arts and Humanities disciplines, it research *only* positions. Where as in sciences there are purely research, commonly at the postdoctoral level, but also occasionally as full-time permanent employees (e.g. PIs research institutes or staff scientists). Most academic philosophers I know are also teachers to one sort or another, even at the Postdoc level.